# Responsive Tables with CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

I have a simple table which if viewed on desktop resolution will display as a normal html table of data. But for mobile devices I want the display to be a little diff.
HTmL code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Booking Time</th>
        <th>Pax</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Mobile</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>07:30PM</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Kevin</td>
        <td>0104321248</td>
        <td>advoworks@hotmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>08:30PM</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>01241234123</td>
        <td>greatone@hotmail.com</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Desktop will display table headers and data rows as per normal.

Mobile version of the table should hide the table headers, and display the data in a 3 row format such as:

```
Time, Pax
Name, Phone number
Email
```

Basically the mobile version will have 3 "rows" for each row of table data, with the original table header hidden.

What I have for CSS now is to hide the table header, but I'm stuck where it comes to rearranging the  columns into rows.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px)  {

th {
    display: none;
}
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Try giving everything a class and controlling them that way.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TTwtf/)

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="cell-time">Booking Time</th>
            <th class="cell-pax">Pax</th>
            <th class="cell-name">Name</th>
            <th class="cell-mobile">Mobile</th>
            <th class="cell-email">Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="cell-time">07:30PM</td>
            <td class="cell-pax">3</td>
            <td class="cell-name">Kevin</td>
            <td class="cell-mobile">0104321248</td>
            <td class="cell-email">advoworks@hotmail.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="cell-time">08:30PM</td>
            <td class="cell-pax">4</td>
            <td class="cell-name">John</td>
            <td class="cell-mobile">01241234123</td>
            <td class="cell-email">greatone@hotmail.com</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px)  {
    thead {
        display: none;
    }
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table, tbody, tr, td {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    tr {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    td {
        padding: 0;
    }
    td.cell-time, td.cell-pax,
    td.cell-name, td.cell-mobile {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ayman, I like your solution. However when I copy and paste the code  into an empty html file, and empty css file, and i manually linked them using <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />, for some reason it looks a little different and the cells don't stack on top of each other when making the browser window smaller. It seems to work on jsfiddle. Is there some other code changes i need to make for the CSS to work? I copied pasted directly. No change to the html/css.

Answer (score 0):

What about attributing classes to the `<td>` elements something like `class="col1"` and `class="col2"` and controlling the layout from that (i.e with floats).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can not modify the structure of HTML Tags like Table, No of Rows and Columns with CSS. 
What you can do is change the CSS of the elements in a way that it rearranges according to screen.

Here you can not split the `<td>` into two rows with CSS, to do that you need to create another `<tr>` and thats not possible with CSS alone.
What you can do is, achieve the table like format with `<div>`.

**Check DEMO** : **http://jsfiddle.net/W327n/1/**

HTML :

```
<div class="master">
    <div class="title">
        <div>Booking Time</div>
        <div>Pax</div>
        <div>Name</div>
        <div>Mobile</div>
        <div>Email</div>
    </div>
    <div class="data clear">
        <div>xxxxx</div>
        <div>xxx</div>
        <div>xxxxxxxx</div>
        <div>xxxxxxxx</div>
        <div>xxxxxxxxxx</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.master{
    width:100%;
    background:#eaeaea;
}
.title div{
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    background:#dadada;
}
.data div{
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    background:#eaeaea;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px)  {
    .title{
        display: none;
    }
    .data div{
        width:50%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple strategy is to set the table and the rows to be displayed as blocks, the cells as inline, and put line breaks between the texts from the cells as desired. Generating line breaks with CSS is a bit tricky (unless you want to generate them both before and after, which you can do with `display: block`): use generated content, with U+000A LINE FEED as content and line breaking (the `white-space` property) set to preformatted text, i.e. to display line breaks as-is.

The following example additionally draws a horizontal line between the records, since I think they should be somehow separated visually. You could alternatively use some vertical margin or alternating background colors.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 760px)  {

th {
    display: none;
}

table, tr {
    display: block;
}

tr {
    border-bottom: solid thin #99c;
}

td {
    display: inline;
}

td:nth-child(2n):after {
    content: "\a";
    white-space: pre;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to write your own responsive tables but if you are looking for a CSS framework, Foundation has some nice ones for them:

http://foundation.zurb.com/responsive-tables.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The following code work for me but its displayed row wise,

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 780px) {
    table tr td {
    display:table;
    display:block;
    }
}
```